# Java equivalent to .NET's ColorBlend

Tags: java, .net, android, colors, drawing

What is the closest equivalent of .NET's [ColorBlend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.colorblend%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) /InterpolationColors  in Java?

Update:
See my own solution below. Also, I needed this for my Android App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer. I was actually looking this for Android for drawing a linear gradient line with multiple colors at various stops. Turns out Android's [LinearGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html)'s constructor takes parameters for both colors and positions. To imitate .net's ColorBlend I'll just create a ColorBlend class with setter/getters for positions and colors.

Answer (score 0):

Nearest seems to be java.awt.[GradientPaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Java SE:

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/ext/awt/LinearGradientPaint.html

(Sun has sponsored this Apache project. It is also part of their JavaFX product line.)